# Project Centennial Error

Tags: vb.net, powershell

I keep getting the same error message over and over. I have checked the logs, and they are useless because the just restate whats printed on the screen. I have tried contacting Microsoft Tech Support but they want $499 to answer my questions. So I know this question is more than likely going to get down voted and get me banned, but it’s my last option and its cheaper than $500. This is the command I entered (yes VLC, trying to recreate Microsoft tutorial) and the error I keep receiving:

```
PS C:\Users\Mark\Desktop\DesktopAppConverter> .\DesktopAppConverter.ps1 -ExpandedBaseImage C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Wind
ows\Images\BaseImage-14393 -Installer C:\Users\Mark\Desktop\VLC\vlc-2.2.4-win32.exe -InstallerArguments "/quiet","/nores
tart" -Destination C:\Users\Mark\Desktop\VLC -PackageName "VLC" -Publisher "CN=VideoLAN" -Version 1.0.0.0 -Verbose
VERBOSE: Log files can be found in C:\DesktopAppConverter\f18ef452-9062-487e-bbee-6599c9157a0d\logs
VERBOSE: Desktop App Converter Preview 0.1.15.release_2016-05-09_12-56_1a4902
VERBOSE: --------------------------------------------------


Checking Prerequisites

VERBOSE: Checking Windows Version to ensure it meets minimum requirements
VERBOSE: Minimum Windows Version requirement is met.
VERBOSE: Testing for required feature enabled...
VERBOSE: An error occurred. Refer to logs in C:\DesktopAppConverter\f18ef452-9062-487e-bbee-6599c9157a0d\logs
Get-WindowsOptionalFeature : An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
At C:\Users\Mark\Desktop\DesktopAppConverter\converter_util\EnvironmentAssertions.ps1:37 char:16
+ ...  $feature = Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName "Containe ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-WindowsOptionalFeature], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Dism.Commands.GetWindowsOptionalFeatureCommand
```

As you can see it starts up and is able to verify my Windows version, then stops at the next prerequisite. Also, in the help description it says "This converter depends on an optional Windows feature being enabled." Does anyone know what feature it is referring to?? As always, thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: I think your best bet would be to post this question [here](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/category/161895-desktop-bridge-centennial?page=1).

Comment: @JimHewitt That's a suggestion line. I have more of a question than suggestion.

Comment: If you scroll down some, you will see some reports of errors

Answer (score 0):

The documentation states that only 64 bit is supported, it is possible you have the wrong binary (vlc-2.2.4-win32.exe)

Comment: That’s not the case. I cannot compile the VLC appx correctly, but not my own. I’m not sure what I’m doing wrong, but at least I now know the program IS working.

Answer (score 0):

The feature being referenced is the "Containers" feature which you should notice when you go to Programs and Features -> Turn Windows features on or off and then in the subsequent window you should see "Containers". That needs to be enabled before you try to run the converter. Did you try setting up the converter using the steps mentioned here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-run-desktop-app-converter? Also, I noticed that you are running an older version of the converter (0.1.15), so you should also try to update to the latest version (0.1.24) - the problem you reported is not related to the version, but still use the latest version.

Comment: I had containers enabled, but I didn’t notice I was using an older version, got it right off the MSDN webpage. So I updated and ran it, it runs farther but still gets stuck creating the final Appx package. The error says 
"W_CANNOT_MAKEAPPX_WITHOUT_EXE
Unable to create appx package without setting the 'Application Executable' property in the AppxManifest.xml. Please set
the 'Application Executable' property in the AppxManifest.xml before calling makeappx manually."
I have tried using -AppExecutable but its not setting, every time it builds it defaults to MyApp.exe

Comment: It says I can edit it, but then I do not know how to call MakeAppx.exe with the same XML file.